# Firebase Cloud Messaging on Android to another Client throws error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I try to send a message from a client to another client using FCM I get no errors in the code, but when I run I get "Incompatible types: Message Cannot be Converted into RemoteMessage".

Here is the code:

```
Message message = Message.builder()
.putData("score", "850")
.putData("time", "2:45")
.setToken(/*Token that I have removed from this post*/)
.build();
String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
Log.d("tokencheck","response after send:" + response);
```

Does anyone know any potential causes for this,or what I could do to figure out what's causing this

Answer (score 1):

FCM doesn't support direct client-to-client messaging.

You're getting that error because [FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#send(com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage)) only accepts a [RemoteMessage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage) type object, and you're passing it something else.  This method is used for [upstream messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream), where you send messages to your backend.

If you want to implement some form of client-to-client messaging, you're going to have to build that yourself using some backend that can deliver the messages.  It can use the Firebase Admin SDK, or the FCM REST API.